# how to response for the email that "the correction have been competed"?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, word-request, word-meaning, difference

The corrections has been updated

or

the corrections have been updated

which one is correct?

Comment: Hi Thendral, welcome to ELL! Your question is basically: is "corrections" singular or plural?

Comment: **The correction/s has/have been completed** is NOT idiomatic English. People would say that **the fault/problem has been fixed/resolved**. If you are asking how to respond to such a statement (however badly worded), you might say something like: **Thank you / Thank you for informing me/ letting me know that the problem has been fixed** or anything similar.

Answer (score 1):

Neither.

The [required] corrections have been done.
Or "... applied" or "... completed".